# Multiple mysqli prepared statements not working together

Tags: php, mysql, forms, select, mysqli

A lot has changed in the PHP world since the last time I was using it (few years back). Now it seems I need to learn again everything, which takes me to my current problem.

```
/* Create a prepared statement */
$stmt1 = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT channel FROM channel WHERE barcode=?");
$stmt2 = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT action FROM action WHERE barcode=?");
$stmt3 = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT reason FROM reason WHERE barcode=?");
$stmt4 = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT supplier_name FROM suppliers WHERE barcode=?");
/* Bind parameters */
$stmt1 -> bind_param("s", $_POST['channel']);
$stmt2 -> bind_param("s", $_POST['action']);
$stmt3 -> bind_param("s", $_POST['reason']);
$stmt4 -> bind_param("s", $_POST['supplier']);
/* Execute it */
$stmt1 -> execute();
$stmt2 -> execute();
$stmt3 -> execute();
$stmt4 -> execute();
/* Bind results */
$stmt1 -> bind_result($channel1);
$stmt2 -> bind_result($action1);
$stmt3 -> bind_result($reason1);
$stmt4 -> bind_result($supplier1);
/* Fetch the value */
$stmt1 -> fetch();
$stmt2 -> fetch();
$stmt3 -> fetch();
$stmt4 -> fetch();


echo "Channel ".$channel1."; Action: ".$action1."; Reason: ".$reason1."; Supplier: ".$supplier1;
```

Eeverything works just fine one by one, but when it's all combined... nothing. Only the first statement will work. What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Are you getting any errors? How do you determine others don't work and first one does? Need more details.

Comment: Only first variable gets echo-ed. Everything else is NULL. That's why I said only the first one is working.

Comment: Well, what I'm seeing that all of your queries are looking for a `barcode`. But you're supplying 4 `$_POST` variables. Might they be empty or contain a nonexistent barcode?

Comment: Probably all four statements should `$stmt1 -> bind_param("s", $_POST['barcode']);` for statements 1-4. You also misspelled `reason` accessing `$_POST[]`.

Comment: Not the case, because I echo-ed the $_POST variables and all have the correct info stored. Tried already with all 4 statements $stmt -> bind_param(...) and still didn't work. Thanks for letting me know about the misspelling.

Answer (score 1):

This happen because:

- [mysqli_stmt::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php):

  > Note:
  >   When using mysqli_stmt_execute(), the mysqli_stmt_fetch() function must be used to fetch the data prior to performing any additional queries.
- [mysqli_stmt::close](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php):

  > Closes a prepared statement. mysqli_stmt_close() also deallocates the statement handle. If the current statement has pending or unread results, this function cancels them so that the next query can be executed.
- The binding (for params and results) can be done before execution... just excludes execute(), fetch() and close() for each statment in one separate block each.

Also take in mind the use of `trigger_error($mysqli->error);` to check possible errors while using `prepare()`.